# Search equals,contains,fulltext,lessthan,greaterthan in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform 4 operations on data which resides in elastic. Exact match(equals),contains,less than ,greater than. There are two options in elastic namely query and filter which from what i have learned so far does the same but query evaluates a score that best matches the data condition-value relation.

What i wanted to do is simple filtering or querying ( I am confused , the way it is mentioned in their site)

1. Exact match like `name=Arjun` or `age=29` or `email=abc@asd.com`
2. Contains like name contains `Ar` or email contains `gmail.com`
3. Greater than like `age>29`
4. Less than like `age<20`

I was using this format so far ( to be frank I didn't had the time to do research and implement)

```
{{ \"query\" : {{ \"filtered\" : {{ \"filter\" : {{ \"bool\" : {{ {{\"match\" : {\"" name "\" : \"" Arjun "\"} }}  }} }} }} }} }}
```

Above format for contains

```
{{ \"query\" : {{ \"filtered\" : {{ \"filter\" : {{ \"bool\" : {{ {\"range\": {\"" age "\": {\"" + gt/lt+ "\": \"" 29 "\"} } } }} }} }} }} }}
```

Above format for greater than or less than

I used the bool expression to combine by filters as per this URL 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_most_important_queries_and_filters.html

As per the link above, we can use bool to combine queries and as per specified in the example
`{
        "bool": {
        "must":     { "match": { "title": "how to make millions" }},
        "must_not": { "match": { "tag":   "spam" }},
        "should": [
            { "match": { "tag": "starred" }},
            { "range": { "date": { "gte": "2014-01-01" }}}
        ]
        }
    }`

i can write the same without the filtered and inside it filter ?

Now i want to implement equals in my (messy) code and i have a feeling that its not so good code either.

Please help me

Comment: i added c# as tag, because i am using C# to create the query and send it using webrequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query like:

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "term": {
              "name": "Arjun"
           }
        },
        {
           "query_string": {
              "default_field": "name",
              "query": "Ar*"
           }
        },
        {
           "range": {
              "age": {
                 "from": 10,
                 "to": 20
              }
           }
        }
       ]
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hi Richa,
term is for exact match right? what is query_string ?

Comment: Yes term is for exact matching and query_string for contains

Comment: Yes, you are right. Both will do that. But `query_string` is  a lot  more than `match`. But for you requirement, both will do the needful

Comment: Regarding query_string , the default_field will be our filtering column and query will be the data to be filtered right?

Comment: Yes, but if you don't define `default_field` your search will occur on `_all` which means on all the fields by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richi, I am starting to learn Elastic which i could not do at the first place due to restricted time.Have accepted your comment as answer :) Cheers

Comment: Richi , the query string you mentioned above search for name that starts with Ar, what if i want to search inbetween words, say the name is Amsterdam and i give dam for search, the above query won't fetch data. :(

Comment: You can use  `* dam *` them in query then

Comment: oops, it was that simple :)